# 2 envelopes. Draw this in one line. Almost IMPOSSIBLE. For me though...

Tags: geometry

How do you do this in one line?
Rules: You cannot draw over a line but you can cross over it.
this is very hard for me. Please help me.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Lnp.jpg)

Comment: Is this about Eulerian circuits?

Comment: This is impossible. There are four points where lines meet, where there are an odd number of lines coming from them. In order for this picture to be drawn in one line, there can only be at most two. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).